# Render Markdown to HTML in Django templates

Tags: django

I would like to render Markdown to HTML so that I could simply write markdown inside my HTML templates.

Example: **home.html**:

```py
#This is a simple markdown in HTML
```

And I would like Django to interpret my Markdown and display it as if it was HTML:

```
<h1> This is a simple markdown in HTML </h1>
```

What would be the easiest way to implement it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to do this, one would need to create a template filter that converts the Markdown text into HTML for the template.

Fortunately this is a common task and there are multiple packages that can help you.

[Django Package](https://github.com/erwinmatijsen/django-markdownify) - For use with django

[Python Markdown](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/) - Python Markdown that you can use within the custom Django template filter